# Is Rust-style ownership and lifetimes possible without Rust-style borrow checking?

Tags: memory-management, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, object-lifetime

Would it be possible for a programming language to consistently have Rust-style ownership and lifetimes (for automatic memory management) while dropping the requirement that only one mutable reference to a piece of data can exist at any time (used to suppress data races)?

In other words, are Rust-style ownership and lifetimes and Rust-style borrow checking two separable concepts? Alternatively, are these two ideas inherently entangled at a semantic level?

Comment: Rust's "automatic memory management" is pretty much the same as in C++. They both use RAII principles.

Comment: @kmdreko doesn't Rust's lifetime semantics allow for something better than what C++ can automatically achieve?

Comment: Lifetimes don't affect the code generation at all, its simply static analysis. So its value is *safety*. Both Rust and C++ have the same *type* of ownership system by having separate value and reference types. They use RAII to destroy values when they go out of scope. So without the borrow-checker, I'd say you get C++.

Comment: Or am I misunderstanding and you're just asking for a language that has drop safety but not data race safety?

Comment: @kmdreko Right, but for example, smart pointers simply drop once out of scope, regardless of where they're passed to in the meantime, which isn't as rich as Rust-style lifetime semantics.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic. While language design questions can be on-topic, speculating on the potential for a language with different features will only invite opinions. Either that or its fishing for language recommendations which is equally off-topic. I suggest posing the question on a separate forum.

Comment: While I agree with kmdreko this is off topic for SO, you might take a look at zig.

Comment: @turbodiesel4598 What do you mean by "regardless of where they're passed to in the meantime"? If you return a `std::unique_ptr` from a function or pass it to a thread, it will not be destroyed when the original goes out of scope - basically the same as `Box` in Rust. It's true that if you take a raw pointer to the contents of a `unique_ptr` that it will not extend the lifetime of the `unique_ptr`, but that's not passing a smart pointer anymore

Comment: I mean, I just asked what I think was a pretty succint question (I asked for an example language purely as a matter of whether what I was asking about had actually been implemented anywhere). I'm not looking for any language recommendations, nor do I think opinions about language design are really relevant.

Comment: @trentcl Maybe I misunderstand how unique_ptr works. My understanding was that if it was passed to some object that lived beyond the scope in which the unique_ptr was created, it would become invalid.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Because this question in its current form appears off-topic, you may wish to look at other resources. More open-ended questions and discussions are welcome on [the Rust users forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/), [the Rust subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/), [the Rust Discord server](https://www.rust-lang.org/community), or [the Stack Overflow Rust chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust).

Comment: @JaredSmith  zig has no concept of references at all, and doesn't support / do RAII either, so it has neither "smart pointer automatic scope-based deallocation" nor "richer compile checks" of them.

Comment: How should I change my question for it to be “more focused”?

Comment: @turbodiesel4598 stack overflow is a Q&A for specific questions about specific code. Open-ended questions are off topic here. Shepmaster already suggested some alternate venues more suited to free-form discussion.

Comment: @Masklinn I don't really know much about zig other than it took aim at the systems programming space. I was spitballing.

Comment: While I was one of the people who voted to close, I've now voted to reopen since OP has focused the question on the relationship between ownership, lifetimes, and borrow-checking, which I see as on-topic and answerable.

Comment: I'll accept Masklinn's answer because I'm getting the feeling there's not much more that could be added. This question wasn't specifically about Rust, it's just that it's the only example I could think of to refer to.

Comment: "Welcome to the on-topic, off-topic administrative police department, your application has been accepted."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would it be possible for a programming language to consistently have Rust-style ownership and lifetimes (for automatic memory management) while dropping the requirement that only one mutable reference to a piece of data can exist at any time (used to suppress data races)?

A language can do anything so sure.

The problem is that dropping this requirement would be an UB-nest in a language like Rust: if you drop mutable references being unique then they have no purpose so you just have references (always mutable) and the only thing they do is be lexically scoped, this means you can hold a reference to a sub-part of an object, and have a second reference mutate the object such that the sub-part is invalidated (e.g. a reference to a vec item and clearing the vec[0]), and the first reference is now *dangling*, it points to garbage.

The way to solve that would be to… add a GC? And from that point on the value of "rust-style ownership and references" becomes… limited to nonexistent, because you need a GC non-lexical automated memory management and your references can keep objects alive so having all types be affine by default isn't very useful.

Now what can be useful (and what some languages explore) is for [sub-normal types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructural_type_system) to be opt-in, so types would be normal by default but could be *opted into* being affine, linear, or even ordered, on a needs basis. This would be *solely* a type safety measure.

> If so, are there any existing languages which achieve this?

Not to my knowledge.

> If not, why not?

Because nobody's written one? Affine types by default are useful to Rust but they're not super useful in general so most of the research and design has focused around linear types, which provide more guarantees and are therefore more useful if only a small subset of your types are going to be sub-normal.

[0] which shows that "data races" are not solely about concurrency, it's an entire class of problems which occur commonly in sequential code (e.g. iterator invalidation)

Comment: Just to be clear, I am not concerned with the issues that re-emerge due to the ability to mutate an object from different places (such as dangling pointers, data races, etc.). The first question solely concerns the ability to consistently implement an ownership and lifetime system to deal with compile-time dropping (no GC) while not enforcing the borrow checks. From your answer I'm not exactly sure whether you're saying yes or no.

Comment: If you want the short version my answer is "sure it's possible but what's the point". What you're asking for is basically C++ with lexical pointers. Certainly not impossible, not sure it's useful.

Comment: Because with such a system, you may be able to achieve more compile-time safety than something like C++ can with its smart pointers (where there is no "lifetime semantics" beyond basic scoping).

Comment: Sure you do achieve more compile-time safety than C++, but the language is still full of holes you're saying you don't care about, so the gain seem… limited. You're basically solving UAF and a subset of dangling pointers and that's about it. And thus I can't imagine it would be worth the effort or building a language competing with C++ or Rust: "better than C++ but not actually good" is not much of a tagline. Feel free to go and explore the space, mind, I just don't see why you would but that's me.